# Javascript: How to extend class properly

Tags: javascript, prototype

Searching over the internet I'm always bumping on this approach of Javascript classes extension

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}
```

But how is that different from this one?

```
  function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var p = new Parent()
    Child.prototype = p
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = p
  }
```

This last one also works perfect. So why should I use this extra `var F = function() { }` move then?

Comment: JavaScript does not have classes. (-:

Comment: It does.. in my imagination ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Especially cookie monster. It makes sense indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoking the original constructor directly  can have undesirable side effects, like not working properly if certain expected arguments are not passed.

That's why they use a "proxy" function, which lets you get a new object that inherits from `Parent()` without actually invoking `Parent()`.

---

Here's a simple example:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    if (name === undefined)
        throw "A name is required";
    this.name = name + "";
    this.age = age;
}
```

If `Person` is the parent, it'll throw  an error because there was no `name` passed.

Comment: hmmm... someone doesn't like this answer? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: But that when used - one have to explicitly call the superclass by using apply(this, aparams) in order to inherit super class fields, right?

Comment: @lukasz1985: That's correct. It would be `Person.apply(this, arguments);` for my example.

Comment: So there's a tradeoff for this method of doing this, which could be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You could also look at object.create

Comment: @lukasz1985: No, it would need to be done either way.

Comment: See 'inheritance' at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: No, in the second case the fields are in the prototype chain

Comment: @lukasz1985: What fields? We can't see the constructors you're passing. ;-P But even so, the fields will be shared between all `Child` objects, and that's usually not what you want. Normally each child will have its own values, and the parent will have the responsibility of applying those values. This means it needs to be done every time you create a child.

Comment: ...if you mean for `Parent` to provide some defaults, then you should put those on `Parent.prototype` (assuming they're primitive values).

Comment: Here are my examples:
1. http://jsfiddle.net/HE5HV/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/mDnF7/1/

Comment: @lukasz1985: Yes, but that's a bit of a contrived example. If you wanted the parent to provide defaults, and they'll be the same for every child, then you could do that. But then if that's the case, you might as will just put them on `Parent.prototype`. Either way, you asked why people don't invoke the constructor directly, and the reason I give above is why.

Comment: But these are not supposed to be defaults, just regular fields that have to vary between instances. "Protected" if you will.

Comment: Then in that case, they won't vary. When you do `Child.prototype = Parent()`, that object is getting the `.foo` value, and that object will be shared between all children until you put a property directly on a child to shadow it.

Comment: You mean "Child.prototype = new Parent()" . Well so what is the solution to let them vary? And indeed there is a difference in this solutions. One doesn't allow the fields to vary while the other does.

Comment: If there's *any* behavior in `Parent` that needs to be applied to every `Child` that is created, then inside the child constructor, you need to do `theParent.apply(this, arguments);` or some variation. That way, the work that `Parent` does is applied to every `Child` as it's created.

Comment: ...but again, you asked why people use the first example, and not the second. The reason is as I explained in my answer. The rest of this doesn't change that reason.

Comment: It was not me who asked the question :)

Comment: @lukasz1985: Ha! Sorry. Lost track of who was who. :D

Comment: BTW: JS OOP is kinda wicked. I'm doing JS for a 2 or 3 years and I'm still confused with this stuff sometimes, while programming in Java I got classess and interfaces in two months.

Comment: @lukasz1985: Yeah, it's... odd. In a way it's deceptively simple. Just a chain of objects, where if a property can't be found on one, it continues the search on the next. What makes it confusing is JavaScript's goofy "constructor functions", which are really nothing more than a way if pairing two objects to form a link in the chain.

Comment: It was helpful. The only thing I don't like about first approach - is that I'd have to put all methods of Parent I'd like to use in Child to Parent prototype instead of it constructor. I mean I can't declare Parent like this anymore   `function Parent(){ this.p_method = function(){ /* do something */ }` But instead I should always use it like `function Parent(){}; Parent.prototype.p_method = function(){/*..*/}`

Comment: @pehas: You can do that. The common pattern would be to put this code in the `Child` constructor: `Parent.apply(this, arguments);`. *(Of course using the actual names you give to the constructors.)* That will call the `Parent` function, set its `this` value as the new object, and pass along whatever arguments were passed to Child. You can also pass along a subset of arguments.

Comment: ...and let me put it this way, if you used your second code example the question, and assigned the method in the `Parent` constructor, that would be identical to putting the method on the `Child.prototype`.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Great stuff. I was not aware of the possibility of calling for another class constructor like that. Many thanks!

Comment: @pehas: You're welcome. And just to be clear, `.apply()` or its very similar sibling `.call()` can be used on basically any function. It's just a way of setting the `this` value of the function you're calling. So this `foo.apply(some_object, ["a", "b", "c"]);` invokes `foo` setting the `this` value of `foo` to `some_object`, and passes `"a"` `"b"` and `"c"` as arguments. Or this `foo.call(some_object, "a", "b", "c");` does the same, but as you see, the arguments are passed individually instead of as an Array.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is (as cookie monster mentioned in the comment) a shim for the following piece of code which might be easier to understand.:

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
  Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
  Child.superclass = Parent.prototype;
}
```

Basically, this implementation makes the object that all Child instances inherit from (Child.prototype) inherit from the object that all Parent instances inherit from (Parent.prototype). Intuitively this is the most accurate representation of class inheritance JavaScript provides.

The second implementation of extends is flawed, because all Child instances will inherit from a specific Parent instance. Should there be significant differences between Parent instances (due to the parameters passed to the constructor for example), the Child instances can not accurate represent that, because they all inherit from a Parent instance created by calling the Parent constructor with no arguments.

Here is an example of what the first implementation can do and the second one can not:

```
function Parent(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Parent.prototype.greet = function() { return 'I am parent ' + this.name; }

function Child(name){
  Parent.call(this, name, 20); // notice the call to the superclass
}
extend(Child, Parent);
Parent.prototype.greet = function() { return 'I am child ' + this.name + ' and i\'m ' + this.age; }

var c = new Child('Tom');
console.log(c.greet()); // I am child Tom and i'm 20
```

As a sidenote, in the Child constructor i have called the Parent constructor. This is actually quite common when dealing with classical inheritance, so that's another point for the first implementation. It isn't actually required, the Child constructor can safely ignore calling the Parent constructor, but keep in mind that that call basically ensures that the new object created is a valid Parent instance before being a child Instance. In my example if you were to not call the Parent constructor, the name and age properties would not be set on the Child instance, so the greet method would return `I am child undefined and i'm undefined`, far from what you would expect.

Comment: It doesn't merge the two prototype. `Child.prototype` will be an object with no own properties, which *inherits* from `Parent.prototype`. It's the same as your `Object.create` version. It's basically an `Object.create` shim coded directly into the `extend` function.

Comment: @Tibos: Yes, much better.  But it's a bit ahistorical to call it this a shim; it existed long before anyone dreamed up `Object.create`.

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile exploring the different ways you can extend and add bits to an object in JavaScript.

Using constructors
    (function (global) {
        function SuperClass() { }

```
    var p = SuperClass.prototype;

    p.doSomething = function() {
        console.log('do something (super)')
    };

    function OtherClass() {
      SuperClass.call(this); 
    }

    OtherClass.prototype = new SuperClass();

    Window.OtherClass = OtherClass;
}(window));

var o = new OtherClass();
```

Using object.create (no double instantiation) - Not supported on all browsers.

```
(function (global) {
    // SuperClass - superclass
    function SuperClass() {

    }

    var p = SuperClass.prototype;

    p.doSomething = function() {
        console.log('do something (super)')
    };

    function OtherClass() {
      SuperClass.call(this); 
    }

    OtherClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

    Window.OtherClass = OtherClass;
}(window));
```

Functional Mixins:
When you want to mixin a generic set of methods/properties into an object.

```
var mixin = function () {
    this.methodA = function () {

    };

    this.methodA = function () {

    };

    return this;
}

var object = function () {
    this.methodB = function () {

    }
}

mixin.call(object.prototype);
```

A very good details explanation of all the methods:

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

Comment: Your first method still has the problem that the OP was asking about and which @cookiemonster explained.  Calling the parent constructor in order to set the prototype of the child can create havoc.  The pattern the OP was asking about is designed to avoid that.  Of course the newer `Object.create` does the same thing more directly.