# What is the correct prototype affectation in javascript inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I read several articles on js inheritance already ([this one](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance), [this one](http://ericleads.com/2013/02/fluent-javascript-three-different-kinds-of-prototypal-oo/), [this one](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), etc.)

In [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) from Mozilla, "classic" inheritance is shown as this : (I uniformized examples)

```
// inherit Base
function Derived() { ... }
Derived.prototype = new Base();            <-------
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;   <-------
```

However in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) I see :

```
// inherit Base
function Derived() { ... }
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);    <-------
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
```

Moreover I have also seen this :

```
Derived.prototype = Base.prototype;
```

And I also experimented and couldn't find the use of `constructor` affectation :

```
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived; <--- it still work if I skip this line
```

if I skip this line, `new Derived()` correctly calls `Derived()` anyway.

So 1) what is correct :

1. `Derived.prototype = new Base();`
2. `Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);`
3. `Derived.prototype = Base.prototype;`
4. other ?

And 2) is `Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;` really needed ? Why ?

Comment: that's the thing about javascript, you can do what you like.. I like John Resig's class.js way of wrapping the prototype nonsense for you, so that you never have to see it in your code.http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: `Object.create()` is a relatively recent command which did not exist previously. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create (the browser compatibility overview is at the bottom of that page). If you use only browsers that have it, use it, otherwise don't - how's that for a ridiculously obvious piece of advice? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Derived.prototype = new Base();
> ```

This does call the `Base` constructor just for setting up the prototype chain. While sometimes working and giving equivalent results to `Object.create`, it is error-prone and should be avoided. Read [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) (and why it should *not* be used).

> ```
> Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
> ```

This is state of the art - [Correct javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance) so to say.

> ```
> Derived.prototype = Base.prototype;
> ```

[This is plain wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088399/1048572). [Do not use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15045080/1048572). It lets `Base` and `Derived` instances inherit from the *same* object - while it (seldom) can be helpful to have multiple constructors for a "class", this is not "subclassing".

> Is `Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;` really needed? Why?

It can be omitted and your script will work nonetheless, but for convenience you would expect that `(new Derived).constructor === Derived`. Also have a look at [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093057/javascript-inheritance-and-the-constructor-property)

Answer (score 1):

**What is the correct way to do classical inheritance in JavaScript**

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20555124/1669279) answer i explained the difference between 1 and 2 showing why 2 is the best way to emulate classical inheritance in JavaScript.

In short, in solution 1 children inherit from an instance of the parent. In solution 2 the class of the children (Derived.prototype) inherits from the class of the parent(Base.prototype). This imposes severe limitations on the parent, because it must be called with 0 arguments.

The 3rd solution is even worse because the prototypes of the Derived and the Base class are the same object, so no method overriding can take place. Even worse, a method defined in Derived.prototype will be available for all Base instances and if a method with the same name had been declared on Base.prototype, it would simply be replaced.

Conclusion: 2 is the true way to do classical inheritance in JavaScript.

**Is setting the constructor property needed**

Setting the `constructor` property on the prototype makes it accessible to all instances. That is simply for convenience, the inheriting part works without it.

Comment: Enlightening. Would you mind helping with the 2nd part of the question as well ?